# Input small on mobile

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color:gray;">
        <div class="circular-portrait">
            <img src="http://cyd.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/trump-1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%">
            <input style="width:100%;;margin-top:25%;font-size:1em;" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

I have a simple page and I don't know why the input is so small. How can I maximize the input in mobile?

Comment: you really couldn't find anything on google??

Comment: @RASG really no

Answer (score 4):

Instead of media you can also use the viewport to rescale the webpage

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can add CSS media queries and set special styles for smaller devices. Here's a quick tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You can set font-size bigger for smaller devices.